# C#: Get value from custom .config file

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, config

I'd like to get a value from this config file from within an MVC view. How is this achieved?

Thanks

**UnsupportedBrowsers.config** (projectRoot/config/..)

```
<UnsupportedBrowsers>
  <Browser alias="Internet Explorer">
    <Version>
      <add key="ie6" value="IE6"/>
      <add key="ie7" value="IE7"/>
      <add key="ie8" value="IE8"/>
    </Version>
  </Browser>
</UnsupportedBrowsers>
```

Comment: XDocument.Load is fine if your config file is a "autonomous" xml file, but you can also associate it in your regular web.config file, using the configSource section attribute. In this case, you'll be able to handle it through MS configuration classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it would be better to do it in the *Controller* rather than in the *View.*

Second, reading an XML file is an easy task, use `XDocument` class for example:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("projectRoot\config\UnsupportedBrowsers.config");
var versionKeys = xDoc.Descendants("Version").First().Descendants();

foreach(var key in versionKeys)
{
  //Do something with the retrived keys..
}
```

**Side note:**

In any case, you're better cache this object in order to avoid of I/O blockings if each new incoming request need to use it.

Comment: Many thanks. The reason for doing it in the Masterview is down to us using Umbraco. This will be a one-off per session check. If the users user-agent exists in the config then we'll render a partial and put something into session storage so the logic isn't repeated. Likewise should they not be using an unsupported browser. Does it not make sense, in this instance, to display this view related logic, in the masterview? cheers